# Get metadata with out query

Tags: custom-metadata

I have LoginAPI__mdt --> record Login --> field URL.
How I can get this field without a query?

The problem was with the metadata version - we need 51 to work with this feature

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done without SOQL queries in Apex:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm
Example from documentation for your Metadata Type:

```
LoginAPI__mdt mc = LoginAPI__mdt.getInstance('Login');
System.debug(mc.URL__c);
```

Comment: Thx! but for some reasons I get - Illegal assignment from sObject to LoginAPI__mdt for this line LoginAPI__mdt mc = LoginAPI__mdt.getInstance('Login');. Or I miss something? Thank you!

Comment: @sartynallid Please, check your exact developerName of LoginAPI__mdt instance. Maybe, it differs from the one in example. I replicate the simplest structure in my Dev org and it works.

Comment: Also, if you have namespace in your metadata type, you should use qualifiedApiName (described in documentation).

Comment: thx a lot!!! It works in dev console (anonymous window). Interesting moment it doest works in Illuminated cloud - before save i catch error and need to Cast to   LoginAPI__mdt LoginAPI__mdt mc = (LoginAPI__mdt) LoginAPI__mdt.getInstance('Login'); - but now it works - Thank you

Comment: Successfully save and run code - error 1System.TypeException: Unsupported sobject type and/or version

Comment: mayby solved https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339818/custom-metadata-types-not-supported-in-apex-classes

Comment: we need to update trigger version in metadata to v 51

Comment: Yes, you are right.